# Python bar-chart-race TypeError: bar_chart_race() got an unexpected keyword argument 'img_label_folder'

Tags: python, charts

I am trying to add images to my bar chart race animations (as per this tutorial https://githubmemory.com/repo/basnetsoyuj/bar_chart_race)

When I attempt to add the image label folder in the bar_chart_race function (eg. **img_label_folder='imagefolder'** , I get the below error.

**TypeError: bar_chart_race() got an unexpected keyword argument 'img_label_folder'**

I cannot find any explanation for why some tutorials appear to have the img_label_folder assignment statement to work without issues, yet I cannot get it operational?

I cannot find img_label_folder in bar-chart_race documentation anywhere either, am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what issues you are facing. If you are using "pip install bar_chart_race" it will link to https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race which does not have the "img_label_folder" function in it. After some research, I found that there is another bar_chart_race package that does have this function, and it can be found here: https://github.com/programiz/bar_chart_race/tree/master/bar_chart_race.
or https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your package first and then try this command below:

`pip install git+https://github.com/programiz/bar_chart_race.git@master`

Hope it helps)